# как выделить числа из списка? Python

Tags: python

```
import re
def sum_by_types(items):
    num_list = [x for x in items if f'{x}'.isdigit()]
    str_list = [x for x in items if not f'{x}'.isdigit()]
    return num_list, str_list

print(sum_by_types([])) #== ("", 0)
print(sum_by_types([1, 2, 3])) #== ("", 6)
print(sum_by_types(["1", 2, 3])) #== ("1", 5)
print(sum_by_types(["1", "2", 3])) #== ("12", 3)
print(sum_by_types(["1", "2", "3"])) #== ("123", 0)
print(sum_by_types(["size", 12, "in", 45, 0])) #== ("sizein", 57)
```

задача: — вернуть 2 значения. Первое — это конкатенация всех строк из заданного списка. Второе представляет собой сумму всех целых чисел из заданного списка.

Не могу понять как выделить числа из списка isdigit() пробовал. Есть еще способы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно проверять типы элементов ([isinstance](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance)):

```
def sum_by_types(items):
    text = ''.join(filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, str), items))
    sum_ = sum(filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, int), items))
    return text, sum_
```

Comment: Догадывался про эту функцию (поисковик меня к ней вел), и Вы уже на примере мне показали прямое применение. Спасибо

Comment: Как то пока сложно с лямбдами вопринимается мне код

Comment: Всегда можно переписать на `x for x in items if isinstance(x, str)`. Мне как-то `x for x` глаз режет. Дело вкуса.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Да и `filter` тут по сути напрашивается, конечно

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy О, вроде можно и без лямбд обойтись: `str.__instancecheck__` и `int.__instancecheck__`

Comment: def sum_by_types(items: List) -> Tuple[str, int]:
    result = ['', 0]
    for item in items:
        result[type(item)==int] += item
    return tuple(result)      Вот такое чудо нашел еще на проверку типа

Comment: `type(item)==int` считется плохим стилем. Повторяющийся `+=` на массивах теряет скорость по мере роста длины результата. Но вообще этот пример можно довести до ума.